# Probability using tree diagram.

Tags: probability

There are three army privates and they are shooting at the same target, each with one 
bullet only. The first private has a 0.8 chance of hitting the target, the second private has a 40% chance of missing the target, and the last private has a probability of 90% of being on target. What is the probability that all three privates will hit the target?
Hint : Use tree diagram.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you explained what you have tried and where you are stuck? Have you read any similar questions on this site?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is assumed the privates' chances of hitting the target are independent of each other, the probability of all three hitting is simply the product of the probabilities of each hitting $=.8\times .6\times .9=0.432$.